# NuGet in DevOps gets 401 from https://botbuilder.myget.org

Tags: nuget, botframework

`NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/experimental/api/v3/index.json. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).`

I'm not 100% sure which package references that URL. Browsing to it manually does in fact prompt for log in. Navigating to the subdomain makes this seem like an 'official' Microsoft channel.

Attempting to update all nuget packages is a mess (x package needs y package at version 1, but z package needs y package at version 3). I'll spend some time updating them one-by-one, but knowing which package is relying on that URL would give me a place to start.

How can I tell which package is using this url? If someone from the BotBuilder team reads this, what should I be watching to make sure I stay on top of deployment breaking updates?

Comment: After updating nuget packages 1 by 1 I've found out where I get prompted to log in to myget: Microsoft.BotFramework.Dialogs. I got that up to the latest version and attempted to run a build through DevOps again, it failed with the same error.

All \*bot\* projects are currently up to date.

Comment: Hmm. I was prompted again for Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependancyCollector. I don't see any connections between that package and BotBuilder; so something else is probably calling that url.

Comment: Are you using streaming extensions. There were users getting *similar* error, and that was due to it being moved. https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/2938

Comment: That github seems pretty applicable, thanks! I'm not able to replicate their fix, but it's a start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the Virtual Assistant template. As Dana V pointed out in the comments, the `Microsoft.Bot.Protocol.StreamingExtensions` package was the problem. This package is needed for voice support in that template at the moment. Since I'm not using voice support I just needed to comment out the `DefaultWebSocketAdapter` class. Then I needed to comment out a line in `Startup` and change the initialization of `MainDialog.` There might have been some other minor errors, but nothing a `//` couldn't fix.